# Regex to split alphanumeric, currency and numeric terms in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to split a string into terms in PHP using preg_split. I need to extract normal words ( \w ) but also currency ( even currency symbol ) and numeric terms ( including commas and decimal points ). Can anyone help me out, as I cannot seem to create a valid regex to use for preg_split to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of things you want to capture?

Comment: I need to extract terms such as:
"1.545"
"$143"
"$13.43"
"1.5b"
"hello"
"G9"

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It looks like you are just trying to capture anything that shows up. you could do a dotall capture easily. It's just `/.+/` or are these in the of a string you need filtered? I don't understand what you are trying to split still.

Comment: No, that's not what I need. I need to extract the above words into an array, hence why I mentioned preg_split. I then intend to use the words one at a time in an inverted index.
So, to make it clearer, I need the following sentence:
"Big brown fox - $20.45"

to result in an array as follows:
- Big
- brown
- fox
- $20.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) instead of `preg_split()` ?

```
$str = '"1.545" "$143" "$13.43" "1.5b" "hello" "G9"'
  . ' This is a test sentence, with some. 123. numbers'
  . ' 456.78 and punctuation! signs.';

$digitsPattern = '\$?\d+(\.\d+)?';
$wordsPattern = '[[:alnum:]]+';

preg_match_all('/('.$digitsPattern.'|'.$wordsPattern.')/i', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: That's quite close to what I need. Is it possible to adjust the regex to exclude the period, except in the middle of numbers?

Example:
"This is a number: 43234. These are some words."
Your solution results in:
Array
(
    [0] => This
    [1] => is
    [2] => a
    [3] => number
    [4] => **43234.**
    [5] => These
    [6] => are
    [7] => some
    [8] => **words.**
)

Comment: I've updated my answer consequently ; could you test with the new regex?

Answer (score 1):

What about `preg_match_all()` each word with this `[\S]+\b` then you get an array with the words in it.

Big brown fox - $20.25 will return

```
preg_match_all('/[\S]+\b/', $str, $matches);

$matches = array(
 [0] = 'Big',
 [1] = 'brown',
 [2] = 'fox',
 [3] = '$20.25'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it solve your problem to split on whitespace? `"/\s+/"`

Comment: Not quite, as I do not want to include punctuations except in numeric terms.